# How to modify Android Intent.extras based on app chosen through createChooser()

Tags: android, android-intent, twitter

From my Android app, I am sending text to 3rd party apps as follows:

```
String subject = "...";
String body = "...";

Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);

Intent it = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share:");
G.act.startActivity(it);
```

This works fine. However, if the user elects to share via email, I want to send different text than if the user elects to share via Twitter (which of course is limited to 140 chars). Is there any way I can receive some sort of callback after the user selects their app in the chooser, and modify the Intent EXTRAS fields before it gets sent to the 3rd party app?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can receive some sort of callback after the user selects their app in the chooser, and modify the Intent EXTRAS fields before it gets sent to the 3rd party app?

No, sorry. You would need to implement your own "chooser" mechanism. You don't even really find out that the user chose *anything*, let alone what specifically they chose, let alone affect changes in what you use based on the selection.

The only way you can achieve anything close to what you seek, using the stock "chooser", is to use `Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`, to have the chooser support multiple `Intent`s to populate what goes in the chooser. However, this only works in cases where you can distinguish the possible destination apps by `Intent`. So, you could have:

- one `ACTION_SENDTO` `Intent` with a `mailto:` `Uri` that would get used by email clients
- the base `ACTION_SEND` `Intent` that would be used by other stuff that can share text

You would provide a longer message in the email-specific `Intent` and a shorter message in the more generic `Intent`.